# Бесконечный ввод чисел в консоли

Tags: c++

Надо считать бесконечный ряд переменных типа `double` с консоли. Например, я ввожу:

> ```
> 100 500.20 800
> ```

жму <kbd>Enter</kbd>, и введенные значения записываются в массив. Как так сделать?

Comment: В чём проблема считать как строку, а потом разбить на числа по пробелу?

Comment: Какой "цикл"? О чем речь вообще? Показывайте код.

Comment: -1. Не ясно, какую работу проделал автор при решении проблемы.

Comment: @Arkady, это настолько примитивный вопрос, что тут даже нету исходной часточки от автора. Что я могу сделать не зная основ, скажем так?

Comment: @Cactus загуглить их, найти несколько вариантов, попробовать каждый, получить проблемы с ними, раз уж Вы новичок, и с этими проблемами (а так же общей - проблемой выбора, как лучше, из найденных вариантов или того, что подскажут отвечающие) уже написать пост =)

Comment: @Arkady, спасибо за заметку, буду знать:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, что-то вроде этого:

```
for(;;)
{
    double n;
    cin >> n;
    // Что-то делаем
    // Если все введено - break;
}
```

**Update**

Если считывание из одной строки - то можно, например, так

```
string s;
getline(cin,s);  // Чтение строки ("до нажатия Enter")
istringstream is(s); // Строковый поток для чтения
double n;
while(is >> n)
{
    // Что-то делаем со считанными числами
}
```

Comment: Да я уже по-всякому пробовал. В том то й фишка, что я не знаю когда конец. Максимум вводимых чисел 1000, и остановка считывания после нажатия энтэр.

Comment: То есть просто нужно считать одну строку и числа в ней? Тогда см. обновленный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

[Чтение до окончания ввода](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hOIOLHNWRyTOSDFy) (в Linux <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, в Windows — <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin), {});
    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

[Чтение в строку до <kbd>Enter</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tmu8IQN8wj2aXNtF) с последующим чтением из строки:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    std::istringstream iss(s);

    std::vector<double> v(std::istream_iterator<double>(iss), {});
    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
}
```